# How to receive in - app push notifications when app is open?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I'm currently using a library called "whisper" that is supposed to help with showing in-app push notifications [Whisper Link](https://github.com/hyperoslo/Whisper)

In my "didReceiveRemoteNotification" I have it set up as follows:

```
  func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    if application.applicationState == .Active {

      let navigationController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController

      if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? NSDictionary {
        if let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSDictionary {
          if let title = alert["title"] as? NSString {
            if let body = alert["body"] as? NSString {

              let announcement = Announcement(title: title as! String, subtitle: body as! String, image: UIImage(named: "HolyGrailLogo-58"))
              Shout(announcement, to: navigationController)
            }

          }
        }
      }

      // Show and hide a message after delay


    }
  }
```

For some strange reason I'm not receiving any push notifications, not sure why.

Comment: Is the app requesting permission from the user to receive push notifications? You should not need to check application.applicationState == .Active

Comment: I'm checking application.applicationState == .Active to see if the app is open.  The user should have already accepted push notifications

Comment: You can check [this community answer](https://support.layer.com/hc/en-us/articles/204632870-How-do-I-troubleshoot-issues-with-Push-Notifications-on-iOS-) for all possible reasons.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check in your device settings that your app is able to receive remote notification.
2. Put a print statement after this method func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification.
3. If it is not printing then issue is with your library.
4. .Active check is not required. When app is in background this method will not execute.